# How to compare my public ip and the visitor remote addr to grant login access in php

Tags: php, authentication, remote-access

Im building a site where i need to login users but i need to grant access only the users that have my same public ip, so i could assume that the login is been performed from the same area. Any help would be very appreciated and am using REMOTE_ADDR to trying to compare.

Comment: Huh? Isn't this what a firewall is for?

Comment: I learn much about firewalls for your comment, and it'was really helpful and interesting thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact, this kind of authorization is UNSAFE, you should use code like this:

```
$ip = getIp();
$authIp = 'IP YOU WANT TO COMPARE TO';

if($ip == $authIp) 
{
//access granted
}

function getIp(){
$ip = '';
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
  return $ip;
}
```

Comment: thanks, how could it be improved to be more safe and also i need to compare the ip every certain time like every minute or a bit more so when i got a different ip address close the current session.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that it is unsafe because headers like `HTTP-X-FORWARDED_FOR` can be easily forged before arriving at the server. So basing a login system on them is, as Ty221 already said, **very unsafe**.

Comment: Missing semicolons after $authIP string and $ip string.

Comment: great thanks now i understood, and is there an alternative more reliable to get both IP, the client and the server to compare and if match grant access?